# Deprecated: Methods with same name

Tags: php, deprecated

I am getting an error

> Deprecated: Methods with the same name as their class will not be constructors in a future version of PHP; DbClass has a deprecated constructor in /storage/emulated/0/htdocs/once.php on line 1237

```
function actionSql() {
    class DbClass { //1237 line
        var $type;
        var $link;
        var $res;
        function DbClass($type) {
            $this->type = $type;
        }
        function connect($host, $user, $pass, $dbname){
            switch($this->type) {
                case 'mysql':
                    if( $this->link = @mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass,true) ) return true;
                    break;
                case 'pgsql':
                    $host = explode(':', $host);
                    if(!$host[1]) $host[1]=5432;
                    if( $this->link = @pg_connect("host={$host[0]} port={$host[1]} user=$user password=$pass dbname=$dbname") ) return true;
                    break;
            }
            return false;
        }
```

Comment: Please do some research before posting. If you just search for the error message (or just your title), you would have found the answer quicker than it took you to write the question.

Answer (score 1):

In PHP 4, you defined constructors with the same name of the class. In PHP 5 and above, it got deprecated, and constructors should be named `__construct`. Just rename the `DbClass($type)` to `__construct($type)`.